# Sum of an checkbox list of items

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox list of items. I want everytime I check items, to be able to display the price of the item and the sales tax for it, sum a subtotal of each value (price and tax) and sum the total cost. This is what I've done so far (the code is a mix from scripts I' ve found online):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>List</title>

<SCRIPT>
function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) {

                gn = 'item'+i;
                elem = document.getElementById(gn);
                if (elem.checked == true) { sum += Number(elem.value); 
            }

        }
    document.getElementById('totalcost').value = sum.toFixed(2);
}
</SCRIPT> 

</head>
<body>
<FORM  >

<table border="1px" align="center">

<tr>
<td>List of Items
<td>Price
<td>Tax
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id='item1'  value="10.00"   onclick="UpdateCost()">item1
<td><INPUT TYPE="text"     id='price1' SIZE=5 value="">
<td><INPUT TYPE="text"     id='tax1' SIZE=5 value="">
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id='item2'  value="15.00"   onclick="UpdateCost()">item2
<td><INPUT TYPE="text"     id='price2' SIZE=5 value="">
<td><INPUT TYPE="text"     id='tax2' SIZE=5 value="">
</tr>

<TR>
<TD>Subtotals
<TD><INPUT TYPE="text" id="subtotal1" value="" SIZE=5>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="text" id="subtotal2" value="" SIZE=5>
</TR>


<tr>
<td>Total Cost:
<td><input type="text" id="totalcost" value="" SIZE=5>
<td><input type="reset" value="Reset">
</tr>

</table>


</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using a framework such as [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) so that you can use declarative data binding to make your code cleaner and simpler. If you are interested I can post an answer demonstrating that.

Comment: I would appreciate that! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working implementation using Knockout.js. The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pJ5Z7/.

The `ViewModel` and `Item` functions define your data structure and logic. Bindings to properties in the view-model are done in the HTML and Knockout will update those dynamically. These are two-way: I left the price values as inputs to illustrate this. If you check an item and change its price, you will see that change reflected in the rest of the model and view (after the input loses focus).

This approach allows for clean separation of concerns and much more maintainable code. Declarative bindings in Knockout and similar libraries help you avoid manual DOM manipulation as well.

If you want to change your dataset, all you have to do is add or remove items in the initialization code:

```
var items = [
    new Item('item1', 10.00),
    new Item('item2', 15.00)
];
```

With the old approach, you would have had to update the DOM as well as all of your logic. This data could even be loaded dynamically from a web service or anywhere else.

I also cleaned up the markup a bit and moved the size definition of `input` elements to CSS. It's better practice to define styles there.

If you want to learn more, just go to the [Knockout website](http://knockoutjs.com/). There are a number of helpful demonstrations and tutorials.

### JavaScript

```
//Main viewModel
function ViewModel(items) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.priceSubtotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var i = 0;
        var items = self.items();
        var sum = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            //Only add up selected items
            items[i].selected() && (sum += parseFloat(items[i].price()));
        }

        return sum.toFixed(2);
    });
    self.taxSubtotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var i = 0;
        var items = self.items();
        var sum = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            //Only add up selected items
            items[i].selected() && (sum += parseFloat(items[i].taxAmount()));
        }

        return sum.toFixed(2);
    });
    self.totalCost = ko.computed(function() {
        return (parseFloat(self.priceSubtotal()) + parseFloat(self.taxSubtotal())).toFixed(2);
    });

    //Functions
    self.reset = function() {
        var i = 0;
        var items = self.items();
        var sum = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].selected(false);
        }
    };
}

//Individual items
function Item(name, price) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.price = ko.observable(price);
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);
    self.taxRate = ko.observable(0.06);
    self.taxAmount = ko.computed(function() {
        return (self.price() * self.taxRate()).toFixed(2);
    });
}

//Initialization with data- this could come from anywhere
var items = [
    new Item('item1', 10.00),
    new Item('item2', 15.00)
];

//Apply the bindings
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(items));
```

### HTML

```
<form>
    <table border="1px" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>List of Items</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Tax</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: items -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" />
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: price"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: selected() ? taxAmount() : ''"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <tr>
            <td>Subtotals</td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: priceSubtotal"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: taxSubtotal"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Total Cost:</td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: totalCost"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Reset" data-bind="click: reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```